# Pagination for search result using flask issues

Tags: python, flask, search, jinja2

I have an issue. I am creating a search results using flask. It works fine but when I am trying 
navigate to next page using page navigate, it shows error:

'TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.' What am I doing wrong ? The codes are shown below:

```
@main.route("/filter", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def filter():  

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int) 

        search_value = request.args.get('search')
        filter0 = "%{0}%".format(search_value)
        filter1 = request.args.get('myselect')
        filter2 = request.args.get('myselect2')
        if filter1 == 'new':

            if filter2 == "All":
                page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int) 
                posts = Post.query.filter(Post.course_name.like(filter0)).filter_by().order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
            return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, filter1 = filter1, filter2 = filter2)
```

```
        {% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
          {% if page_num %}
            {% if posts.page == page_num %}
              <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.filter', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% else %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.filter', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% else %}
            ...
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if filter1 != 'new'`, the view function return nothing,

The following code might solve this problem

```
@main.route("/filter", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def filter():  

    if request.method == 'GET':
        pass
        if filter1 == 'new':
            if filter2 == "All":
               pass
            return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, filter1 = filter1, filter2 = filter2)
    return 'something'
```